# local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: django-forms

My View :

```
def refer(request, seek_id):
    seek_obj = SeekSolutions.objects.get(pk = seek_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SeekReferForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.refferer = request.user
            obj.seek_id = seek_obj
            obj.save()
            send_message(obj)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/seek/referred')
    return render_to_response('seek/refer.html', {'form' : form , } )
```

Traceback :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in wrapper
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in inner
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func
                return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in changelist_view
            'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)}, ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__
                self._result_cache = list(self.iterator()) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in iterator
        for row in compiler.results_iter(): ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in results_iter
        for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI): ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is pretty old, since I ran in to the same problem(and just solved it) I think I ought to answer to it for future references. But then I had a different error. But you seem to be missing something in your code.

```
def refer(request, seek_id):
seek_obj = SeekSolutions.objects.get(pk = seek_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SeekReferForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        obj.refferer = request.user
        obj.seek_id = seek_obj
        obj.save()
        send_message(obj)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/seek/referred')
else:
    form = SeekReferForm()
return render_to_response('seek/refer.html', {'form' : form , } )
```

This includes an `else` block to your first `if`. This is because when you try to access the url from your browser, you are essentially doing a `GET` request on the resource. As a result the first if is violated and comes directly to the `return` statement where it tries to return a dictionary item with `'form'` as the `key` and a `form` object which was never created at all. Thus the error in your code. There need to be an else part which is supposed to instantiate the `form` object in case you try to open the url in your browser. I hope that helps the cause.

Answer (score 0):

the **form** is instantiated only when request.method == 'POST'.